# Updating a table based on values from previous row

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, rdbms

I have a table and I want to update the Values in the table based on values from the previous row. Here i want to update "Value" as the sum of previous row Value + Adjustment. I would like to do it in SQLite.

Original Table

```
Name  | Value | Adjustment 
Apple |  10   | 5
Ball  |  20   | 10
Cat   |  30   | 15
Dog   |  40   | 0
Emily |  50   | 10
Frog  |  60   | 0
Goat  |  70   | 5
```

Updated Table

```
Name  | Value       | Adjustment 
Apple |  10         | 5
Ball  |  15 (10+5)  | 10
Cat   |  25 (15+10) | 15
Dog   |  40 (25+15) | 0
Emily |  40 (40+0)  | 10
Frog  |  50 (40+10) | 0
Goat  |  50 (50+0)  | 5
```

I can do it using python but i was wondering if there is fast and efficient way of doing it in SQLite.

Comment: Pretty sure you could do it pure SQL in recent versions of SQLite3 with a row_number(), and an INSERT SELECT... If this isn't answered by the time I get home, I'll play with it and post an answer if I find it

Comment: SQL tables have no order; SQL result sets have order. So define "previous" & explain what you mean by "table" since there is no "previous row" in an SQL table. After you define it this will be a faq.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a recent version of sqlite (3.25 or newer), it's pretty easy to do with window functions. The following assumes you're ordering by the name column like in the example input and output:

```
CREATE TABLE example(name TEXT, value INTEGER, adj INTEGER);
INSERT INTO example VALUES('Apple',10,5);
INSERT INTO example VALUES('Ball',20,10);
INSERT INTO example VALUES('Cat',30,15);
INSERT INTO example VALUES('Dog',40,0);
INSERT INTO example VALUES('Emily',50,10);
INSERT INTO example VALUES('Frog',60,0);
INSERT INTO example VALUES('Goat',70,5);
CREATE INDEX example_idx_name ON example(name); -- Used in the window ordering
SELECT name AS "Name"
     , first_value(value) OVER names + sum(adj) OVER names - adj AS "Value"
     , adj AS "Adjustment"
FROM example
WINDOW names AS (ORDER BY name)
ORDER BY name;
```

produces:

```
Name        Value       Adjustment       
----------  ----------  ----------
Apple       10          5         
Ball        15          10        
Cat         25          15        
Dog         40          0         
Emily       40          10        
Frog        50          0         
Goat        50          5
```

Now, for updating the table instead... the problem with `UPDATE` is that rows are updated in arbitrary order (Probably by rowid, but you shouldn't depend on implementation details like that), so you can't really do something based on the "previous" row. One approach: Use a version of the above query to populate a temporary table, and then use that to update the original:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE staging(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value INTEGER);
INSERT INTO staging
    SELECT rowid, first_value(value) OVER names + sum(adj) OVER names - adj
    FROM example WINDOW names AS (ORDER BY name);
UPDATE example AS e SET value = (SELECT value FROM staging AS s WHERE s.id = e.rowid);
DROP TABLE staging;
SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY name;
name        value       adj       
----------  ----------  ----------
Apple       10          5         
Ball        15          10        
Cat         25          15        
Dog         40          0         
Emily       40          10        
Frog        50          0         
Goat        50          5
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to load it into a `pandas` DataFrame via [`.read_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html), calculate the next `Value` cell values and dump back into SQLite via [`.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), something along these lines:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect(...)

df = pd.read_sql_table(name_of_table, conn)

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.iloc[i, 1] = df.iloc[i - 1, 1] + df.iloc[i - 1, 2]

df.to_sql(name=name_of_table, con=conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Please be careful with the `"replace"` `if_exists` behaviour - it would drop the table before inserting new rows.

Comment: SQL tables have no order; SQL result sets have order. So "previous row" doesn't make sense for a "table", so you can't be answering the question, because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @philipxy well, you are right, of course and thanks for the comment. I've assumed the OP has "previous row" notion defined based on an index or value of some other field. I am taking it from there and trying to provide a way to go about solving the problem.